# Where do I get the OSX volume for replacing "/"

Tags: swift, macos, file, system, canonical-form

In Swift 3.0 I get the file name

```
"/Volumes/MacOS/temp/file.txt"
```

Next time I get

```
"/temp/file.txt"
```

To make them matching I need to replace "/" by "/Volumes/MacOS" or vice versa. But where do I get the information that "/" stands for "/Volumes/MacOS"?

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397131/get-fullpath-or-convert-to-fullpath?

Comment: Yes, that's belongs to the same problem.